# How to handle shell script exceptions/errors in OOZIE?

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie, cloudera-cdh, oozie-coordinator

As a part of OOZIE batch i.e.in my workflow,I have scheduled one shell action,it contains number of shell commands to process the data in customized form.

suppose if any exception/error occurred in one of the command by the time of processing,is it possible to handle exception/errors in OOZIE side?

OR

How can I handle in this scenario?

I want to handle in oozie side. please help me on this.

Thanks In advance. :)

i tried below code but i am getting error.

```
<workflow-app name="My_Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
<start to='shell1' />
<action name='shell1'>
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
              <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
              <value>default</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <exec>java</exec>
           <argument>${nameNode}/user/cloudera/shelltest.sh</argument>
           <file>${nameNode}/user/cloudera/shelltest.sh#shelltest.sh</file> 
           <capture-output/>
    </shell>

    <ok to="check-output"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>


<decision name="check-output">
    <switch>
        <case to="1">
          ${wf:actionData("shell1")["error.on"]}
        </case>
        <default to="fail"/>
    </switch>
</decision>
<kill name="fail">
    <message>Script failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name='end' />
```

my shelltest.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
cp /Volumes/Documents/criticalfile.txt /Volumes/BackUp/.
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
echo "[Error] copy failed!" 1>&2
exit 1
fi
```

when i am running oozie job getting below error

```
Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-pattern-valid: Value '1' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '([a-zA-Z_]([\-_a-zA-Z0-9])*){1,39}' for type 'IDENTIFIER'
```

please let me know anything i missed.

Comment: Oozie does not care about application errors, it just cares about *(a)* the final return code for the shell, and *(b)* if you have set the `<capture_output/>` option, the custom output in "key=value" format that you have generated in the shell. Everything that goes to STDERR is ignored.

Comment: Bottom line: you have to trap the errors inside the shell, by checking the return code `$?` of each command. Then you can decide to either make a hard stop with an `exit 1` (and Oozie will switch to the "error" branch); or make a soft stop, with some kind of execution report such as `echo error.on=step5` then `exit 0` (Oozie will switch to the "ok" branch), then use a Decision node to check the value of `${wf:actionData("MyShellAction")["error.on"]}` and react accordingly.

Comment: <workflow-app name="My_Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to='shell1' />
    <action name='shell1'>
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                  <value>default</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <exec>java</exec>

Comment: <argument>${nameNode}/user/cloudera/shelltest.sh</argument>
               <file>${nameNode}/user/cloudera/shelltest.sh#shelltest.sh</file> 
               <capture-output/>
        </shell>

        <ok to="check-output"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
 <decision name="check-output">
        <switch>
            <case to="1">
              ${wf:actionData("shell1")["error.on"]}
            </case>
            <default to="fail"/>
        </switch>
    </decision>
    <kill name="fail">

Comment: <message>Script failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end' />
</workflow-app>

Comment: Hi Samson,as per my understanding based on your comment above i have created above workflow xml, but when i am trying to run as a oozie job,i am getting error like "  "Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-pattern-valid: Value '1' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '([a-zA-Z_]([\-_a-zA-Z0-9])*){1,39}' for type 'IDENTIFIER'.  "  "

Comment: can please help me on this ,is there anything i have missed...Thanks  In advance.

Comment: Your "switch" does not make any sense. Read the documentation, and also some tutorial such as http://hadooped.blogspot.com/2013/09/apache-oozie-part-12-passing-output.html especially, in your case, section 9a